# Dapper Contrib Insert MatchNamesWithUnderscores mapper isn’t working

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, dapper-extensions, micro-orm

The `Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores` isn’t working for inserts. The mapper works fine for the `Get<>` method. I'm using the follow versions in my ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 project together with postgres database.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Dapper": "1.50.0-rc2",
    "Dapper.Contrib": "1.50.0-beta8"
}
```

**Code snippet**

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
    long id = conn.Insert(new Foo { Name = "new foo", LocationId = 3});

    return id;
}
```

**The executed insert SQL stetement**

```
insert into foo ("Name", "LocationId") values ($1, $2) RETURNING Id
```

**Foo class**

```
[Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Table("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

**Foo table**

```
CREATE TABLE "foo" (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "location_id" INTEGER REFERENCES "location" (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There the open issue on github](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/515)

Answer (score 2):

Dapper.Contrib does the insert and it looks like Dapper.Contrib doesn't even reference MatchNamesWithUnderscores. You can open an issue on dapper's github maybe but it doesn't look easy to change.